# Camera location problems in Agisoft Photoscan/Metashape

Tags: 3d, photo, camera-calibration

I use Agisoft Photoscan/Metashape to perform 3D-photogrammetry on deer antlers. I took photos of rotating antlers (with a greenscreen as background), with approximately 100/130 photos per antler. The antlers have 5 pairs of stickers on them (each with a distance of 20 cm).

In some cases, I have difficulty with the software choosing the camera locations of the photos after aligning photos. The software thinks that all photos are being taken from the same place. I tried to prevent this since I used the greenscreen as background.

I already tried to add markers on the stickers I placed beforehand. However, the markers are not being recognized it the other photos but put on random locations (even after adding markers to +10 photos manually).

The weird thing is that the problem happens randomly, not every antler project is doing this. Some antler photos do align in the right camera location, but some other antlers do not. I took a look at the photos, but they look quite the same and are being taken in de same way.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: so your question is about a commerical software program?

Comment: My question is about this problem in agrisoft photoscan, which I use for my thesis research.

Comment: this isn't a programming question, not that I can see. voting to close. please contact the company and/or find their community forum.